# Will upgrading fix the FreeBSD 8.1 portstree?

Tags: freebsd, ports

I have a machine running FreeBSD and the ports tree is accidentaly updated to one of FreeBSD 8 stable. The problem is that my FreeBSD 8.1 is not configured to use PKG for packages so I cannot update or install packages.

I want to upgrade the machines FreeBSD but get the ports tree in working order before I do that.

It seems the only solution is installing an old 8.1 version of the ports tree, but I cannot find any. 
Can someone tell me where to find this?

Would upgrading to the lastest stable version 8 also solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the "8.1" tree, you can find that by using svn to checkout `ports/tags/RELEASE_8_1_0` instead of `ports/head` but keep in mind this tree is going to be terribly out dated and have lots of insecure software and many things are not even going to fetch properly any more. This is probably not the way to go.

Instead, you are better off upgrading to 8.1, but that is one of two steps needed to fix your situation. The other step is to switch to pkg(ng). The way to do that is to run `pkg2ng`. See [the handbook section on pkgng](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/pkgng-intro.html) for more details. Running `pkg2ng` is a one time operation and doesn't require rebuilding or re-installing all your ports. Instead this just tells pkg about the existing software so it can manage it.

Comment: Till now I had no luck fixing it, I think I tried pkg2ng, not sure anymore. I am going to ready and try.

I guess you mean upgrading 8.1 to the last 8 release?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I mean upgrading to 8.4 RELEASE. If you've run pkg2ng already you don't want to run it again. Once you run it you want to make sure you have WITH_PKGNG=yes in /etc/make.conf or are running a version of the OS/ports where it's default (such as 8.4). If you've installed packages/ports since running it and weren't using pkg, you may need to do something to fix things up. Link to handbook section works here.

Comment: The link works now. I hope I did not do something irreversable. The strange thing is that both my host system as my jails have a broken ports tree, though they are updated independantly.
Even when I just run pkg_version I get messages like "Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 1749: Malformed conditional (defined(USE_LDCONFIG) && ${USE_LDCONFIG:tl} == "yes")
Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.sites.mk", line 953: Malformed conditional (!empty(_PERL_CPAN_ID) && ${_PERL_CPAN_FLAG:tl} == "cpan")
Unknown modifier 't'
"

Comment: Well, yeah, pkg_Version isn't going to work. Go read the pkgng docs. :)

Comment: I will, but I did not mean to fix it with pkg_version, just wanted to illustrate that even that tool doesn't work ;-)

Comment: If you are going to upgrade FreeBSD to 9.2 of 10.0, you should just remove all ports and re-install them after the upgrade. That it the recommended procedure after upgrading to a higher major version number.